# How can I get local and session storage values using http request in C#?

Tags: c#, api, http

I want to get local and session storage values from http response in C#. Currently I am using this code:

```
  var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://csdj48vyje.execute-api.us-east 1.amazonaws.com/dev/product");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/plain";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        httpWebRequest.UserAgent = "PostmanRuntime/7.26.5";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        httpWebRequest.Timeout = 40000;
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 2):

`localstorage` and `sessionstorage` are data stores inside the users browser. The values are not sent via an HTTP Request so there is no way of getting the values in the backend without explicitly sending them from the frontend.